# UI-sref with directive click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a way to use ui-sref with a directive that has a click event inside of it?

I want to PREVENT the ui-sref from firing (but still use the ui-sref as an attribute in the directive). In short, I will fire a $state.go inside my directive, but I don't want it to fire by the ui-sref:

```
let directive = {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        upgradeUser: '=',
        upgradeType: '@',
        uiSref: '@'
    },
    controller: function($scope, $element) {

        $element.on('click', function() {
            // prevent ui-sref and check for permissions, if no permissions, do a totally different thing

            if (permissions) {
                $state.go($scope.uiSref)
            } else {
                upgradeService.launchDialog($scope.upgradeUser, $scope.upgradeType)
            }
        })
    }
};

return directive;
```

I've tried passing in event and doing event.preventDefault but that didn't appear to work.

Comment: Probably need to remove the `ui-sref` attribute and compile element again

Comment: e.reventDefault just works https://next.plnkr.co/edit/zOFC5qv9S1t0ZizY

Comment: I've tried preventDefault and it did not work. Does the order of directive vs ui-sref matter? I'll try that

Comment: As a note I am using a controller, not a link function